Why does Perl assign a hash reference as value for a non-existent key?
I am using Perl5 (revision 24 subversion 1) on linux.
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fruit_colors = {
        'apple' => {'red' => 'good'}
};

print($fruit_colors->{'orange'}); # this prints nothing

print($fruit_colors->{'orange'}{'orange'}); # this prints nothing too

print($fruit_colors->{'orange'}); # but this suddenly prints 'HASH(0x1f63098)'



My question is why does this happen? and how to prevent it from causing unintential consequences.

I was looking for some official docs on autovivification, but couldn't find any. I did find a Wikipedia page, a fairly detailed search result from official docs and the autovivification module on metacpan.

Autovivifaction is in perlref. The perdoc page names are not great for discoverability (I first looked in perldata, which led to perlref). I sometimes search first by getting the perl docs with something like perldoc -l perldata | xargs dirname | xargs grep -R -I autovivification.

Also, searching perldoc.perl.org leads to perlref too, as TLP already showed. The trick is that you have to search within that doc because that "Autovivification" section says almost nothing, but it's explained later.

@briandfoy It's a fairly important concept, maybe it deserves a better presentation in the docs.
